# Any ROS node for people (legs) tracking?

Tags: ros, kinect, laser, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all, I would like to provide turtlebot with a decent people tracking capability, first for [turtlebot_follower](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_follower) but maybe also for other more sophisticated behaviors. After a fast survey, I found the following packages:

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/people_tracker        uses OpenNI skeleton tracker
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/ppl_detection         also full body, only until electric
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/lidar_tracking        laser-based, not robust, cannot find code!
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/cyphy_people_mapping  also full body, make a map following people

So none of them is useful for the standard turtlebot configuration, as it can only "see" the people's legs. I have also searched for papers; there're tons of them, but I didn't find a reasonably recent opensource implementation.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72511/any-ros-node-for-people-(legs)-tracking?/) by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2284 on 2013-08-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-08-12**:
What about http://ros.org/wiki/srs_leg_detector ? No idea if it works or not... But maybe you can give it a try.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-08-15**:
Thanks. I completely failed to locate this package!

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-08-15**:
Please let us know if it works ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[My fork of the people stack](https://github.com/DLu/people).

I intend to push this stuff into the main people stack with debs but haven't had time to polish everything.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-08-15**:
Thanks!  looks like what I'm looking for. I'll not try it by now, but I'll give you feedback as soon as I try it (maybe september)